# Using MockedProvider results in error "No more mocked reponses for the query" in jest-react

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme, react-apollo

I have been trying to test a react functional component , which uses apollo-react to fetch data. I am constantly getting the error : **No more mocked reponses for the query** . I have tried various solutions and nothing worked. Here is test case :

```
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import ProcessDetailsPage from '../ProcessDetailsPage';
import { MockedProvider } from '@apollo/react-testing';
import wait from 'waait';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { GetProcessInstanceByIdDocument, ProcessInstanceState } from '../../../../graphql/types';
// import { act } from 'react-dom/test-utils';

const props = {
  match: {
    params: '8035b580-6ae4-4aa8-9ec0-e18e19809e0blmnop'
  }
};

const mocks = [
  {
    request: {
      query: GetProcessInstanceByIdDocument,
      variables: {
        id: '201a8a42-043e-375a-9f52-57c804b24db4'
      }
    },
    result: {
      data: {
        ProcessInstances: [
          {
            id: '201a8a42-043e-375a-9f52-57c804b24db4',
            processId: 'travels',
            processName: 'travels',
            businessKey: 'MQQ640',
            parentProcessInstanceId: null,
            parentProcessInstance: null,
            roles: [],
            variables:
              '{"flight":{"flightNumber":"MX555","seat":null,"gate":null,"departure":"2020-05-08T03:30:00.000+05:30","arrival":"2020-05-09T03:30:00.000+05:30"},"hotel":{"name":"Perfect hotel","address":{"street":"street","city":"Bengaluru","zipCode":"12345","country":"India"},"phone":"09876543","bookingNumber":"XX-012345","room":null},"trip":{"city":"Bengaluru","country":"India","begin":"2020-05-08T03:30:00.000+05:30","end":"2020-05-09T03:30:00.000+05:30","visaRequired":false},"traveller":{"firstName":"Ajay","lastName":"Jaganathan","email":"ajaganat@redhat.com","nationality":"Polish","address":{"street":"Bangalore","city":"Bangalore","zipCode":"560093","country":"Poland"}}}',
            state: ProcessInstanceState.Active,
            start: '2020-05-07T06:50:18.274Z',
            lastUpdate: '2020-05-07T06:50:18.502Z',
            end: null,
            addons: [
              'process-management',
              'infinispan-persistence',
              'prometheus-monitoring'
            ],
            endpoint: 'http://localhost:8080/travels',
            serviceUrl: 'http://localhost:8080',
            error: null,
            childProcessInstances: [
              {
                id: 'bfde98ed-0cdd-4700-ae87-377f7ec430cd',
                processName: 'HotelBooking',
                businessKey: null
              },
              {
                id: 'e607b2a9-0aca-4788-9623-dd2e156ce9c4',
                processName: 'FlightBooking',
                businessKey: null
              }
            ],
            nodes: [
              {
                id: '39d5fe7c-4e37-44ce-8d25-05a4a29ec6ea',
                nodeId: '17',
                name: 'Book Hotel',
                enter: '2020-05-07T06:50:18.429Z',
                exit: '2020-05-07T06:50:18.439Z',
                type: 'SubProcessNode',
                definitionId: '_1A708F87-11C0-42A0-A464-0B7E259C426F'
              },
              {
                id: '1d3d7ebe-79ec-4848-b1d6-d7c5a371b4dd',
                nodeId: '8',
                name: 'Confirm travel',
                enter: '2020-05-07T06:50:18.443Z',
                exit: null,
                type: 'HumanTaskNode',
                definitionId: '_2140F05A-364F-40B3-BB7B-B12927065DF8'
              },
              {
                id: '4fc774f5-c429-4b97-8981-bd60d1f59954',
                nodeId: '7',
                name: 'Join',
                enter: '2020-05-07T06:50:18.442Z',
                exit: '2020-05-07T06:50:18.443Z',
                type: 'Join',
                definitionId: '_5D0733B5-53FE-40E9-9900-4CC13419C67A'
              },
              {
                id: '60309b28-1dbe-49c3-b0d8-8cefb86be8b4',
                nodeId: '10',
                name: 'Book Flight',
                enter: '2020-05-07T06:50:18.439Z',
                exit: '2020-05-07T06:50:18.442Z',
                type: 'SubProcessNode',
                definitionId: '_F543B3F0-AB44-4A5B-BF17-8D9DEB505815'
              },
              {
                id: 'efa5a6c0-9470-4405-8609-620bdbfbb6d9',
                nodeId: '2',
                name: 'Book',
                enter: '2020-05-07T06:50:18.428Z',
                exit: '2020-05-07T06:50:18.439Z',
                type: 'Split',
                definitionId: '_175DC79D-C2F1-4B28-BE2D-B583DFABF70D'
              },
              {
                id: 'acc87f1f-e436-4364-b4d3-9069ddb359c9',
                nodeId: '14',
                name: 'Join',
                enter: '2020-05-07T06:50:18.428Z',
                exit: '2020-05-07T06:50:18.428Z',
                type: 'Join',
                definitionId: '_B34ADDEE-DEA5-47C5-A913-F8B85ED5641F'
              },
              {
                id: '6c20729a-3e2b-44c5-af5c-8554f21a7ebf',
                nodeId: '15',
                name: 'is visa required',
                enter: '2020-05-07T06:50:18.427Z',
                exit: '2020-05-07T06:50:18.428Z',
                type: 'Split',
                definitionId: '_5EA95D17-59A6-4567-92DF-74D36CE7F35A'
              },
              {
                id: '3fb92a0a-e88b-45a4-a48b-65f11a679b96',
                nodeId: '5',
                name: 'Visa check',
                enter: '2020-05-07T06:50:18.278Z',
                exit: '2020-05-07T06:50:18.427Z',
                type: 'RuleSetNode',
                definitionId: '_54ABE1ED-61BE-45F9-812C-795A5D4ED35E'
              },
              {
                id: '2860e474-dffc-498c-8731-e6b6f0b5d4d4',
                nodeId: '16',
                name: 'StartProcess',
                enter: '2020-05-07T06:50:18.276Z',
                exit: '2020-05-07T06:50:18.278Z',
                type: 'StartNode',
                definitionId: '_1B11BEC9-402A-4E73-959A-296BD334CAB0'
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
];

// const waitForComponentToRender = async (wrapper: any) => {
//   await act(async () => {
//     await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000));
//     wrapper.update();
//   });
// };

describe('Process Details Page component', () => {
  it('Sample test case', async () => {
    const wrapper = mount(
      <MockedProvider mocks={mocks} addTypename={false}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <ProcessDetailsPage {...props} />
        </BrowserRouter>
      </MockedProvider>
    );
     // waitForComponentToRender(wrapper)
     await wait(0);
     wrapper.update()
     console.log(wrapper.debug())
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

and here is the query that I am using :

```
export const GetProcessInstanceByIdDocument = gql`
  query getProcessInstanceById($id: String) {
    ProcessInstances(where: { id: { equal: $id } }) {
      id
      processId
      processName
      businessKey
      parentProcessInstanceId
      parentProcessInstance {
        id
        processName
        businessKey
      }
      roles
      variables
      state
      start
      lastUpdate
      end
      addons
      endpoint
      addons
      serviceUrl
      error {
        nodeDefinitionId
        message
      }
      childProcessInstances {
        id
        processName
        businessKey
      }
      nodes {
        id
        nodeId
        name
        enter
        exit
        type
        definitionId
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

here is the stack trace of the error:

```
   console.log
      ApolloError: Network error: No more mocked responses for the query: query getProcessInstanceById($id: String) {
        ProcessInstances(where: {id: {equal: $id}}) {
          id
          processId
          processName
          businessKey
          parentProcessInstanceId
          parentProcessInstance {
            id
            processName
            businessKey
          }
          roles
          variables
          state
          start
          lastUpdate
          end
          addons
          endpoint
          addons
          serviceUrl
          error {
            nodeDefinitionId
            message
          }
          childProcessInstances {
            id
            processName
            businessKey
          }
          nodes {
            id
            nodeId
            name
            enter
            exit
            type
            definitionId
          }
        }
      }
      , variables: {}
          at new ApolloError (/home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/node_modules/apollo-client/bundle.umd.js:92:26)
          at ObservableQuery.getCurrentResult (/home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/node_modules/apollo-client/bundle.umd.js:218:20)
          at QueryData.getQueryResult (/home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/node_modules/@apollo/react-hooks/lib/react-hooks.cjs.js:357:56)
          at QueryData._this.getExecuteResult (/home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/node_modules/@apollo/react-hooks/lib/react-hooks.cjs.js:111:26)
          at QueryData.execute (/home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/node_modules/@apollo/react-hooks/lib/react-hooks.cjs.js:160:47)
          at /home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/node_modules/@apollo/react-hooks/lib/react-hooks.cjs.js:518:55
          at useDeepMemo (/home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/node_modules/@apollo/react-hooks/lib/react-hooks.cjs.js:465:14)
          at useBaseQuery (/home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/node_modules/@apollo/react-hooks/lib/react-hooks.cjs.js:517:16)
          at Object.useQuery (/home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/node_modules/@apollo/react-hooks/lib/react-hooks.cjs.js:539:10)
          at Object.useGetProcessInstanceByIdQuery (/home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/packages/management-console/src/graphql/types.tsx:1253:27)
          at ProcessDetailsPage (/home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/packages/management-console/src/components/Templates/ProcessDetailsPage/ProcessDetailsPage.tsx:49:9)
          at renderWithHooks (/home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:15108:18)
          at updateFunctionComponent (/home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:16925:20)
          at beginWork$1 (/home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:18498:16)
          at beginWork$$1 (/home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:23193:14)
          at performUnitOfWork (/home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22211:12)
          at workLoopSync (/home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22185:22)
          at renderRoot (/home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21878:11)
          at runRootCallback (/home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21554:20)
          at /home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11353:24
          at unstable_runWithPriority (/home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:643:12)
          at runWithPriority$2 (/home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11305:10)
          at flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl (/home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11349:7)
          at flushSyncCallbackQueue (/home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11338:3)
          at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (/home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21431:9)
          at dispatchAction (/home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:15816:5) {
        graphQLErrors: [],
        networkError: Error: No more mocked responses for the query: query getProcessInstanceById($id: String) {
          ProcessInstances(where: {id: {equal: $id}}) {
            id
            processId
            processName
            businessKey
            parentProcessInstanceId
            parentProcessInstance {
              id
              processName
              businessKey
            }
            roles
            variables
            state
            start
            lastUpdate
            end
            addons
            endpoint
            addons
            serviceUrl
            error {
              nodeDefinitionId
              message
            }
            childProcessInstances {
              id
              processName
              businessKey
            }
            nodes {
              id
              nodeId
              name
              enter
              exit
              type
              definitionId
            }
          }
        }
        , variables: {}
            at MockLink.request (/home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/node_modules/@apollo/react-testing/lib/react-testing.cjs.js:85:13)
            at execute (/home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/node_modules/apollo-link/src/link.ts:131:10)
            at QueryManager.getObservableFromLink (/home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/node_modules/apollo-client/bundle.umd.js:2051:89)
            at /home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/node_modules/apollo-client/bundle.umd.js:2106:32
            at new Promise (<anonymous>)
            at QueryManager.fetchRequest (/home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/node_modules/apollo-client/bundle.umd.js:2105:14)
            at QueryManager.<anonymous> (/home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/node_modules/apollo-client/bundle.umd.js:1466:38)
            at step (/home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:139:27)
            at Object.next (/home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:120:57)
            at /home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:113:75
            at new Promise (<anonymous>)
            at __awaiter (/home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:109:16)
            at QueryManager.fetchQuery (/home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/node_modules/apollo-client/bundle.umd.js:1404:35)
            at QueryManager.observeQuery (/home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/node_modules/apollo-client/bundle.umd.js:1862:19)
            at ObservableQuery.setUpQuery (/home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/node_modules/apollo-client/bundle.umd.js:507:20)
            at ObservableQuery.onSubscribe (/home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/node_modules/apollo-client/bundle.umd.js:471:14)
            at /home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/node_modules/apollo-client/bundle.umd.js:139:22
            at new Subscription (/home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/node_modules/zen-observable/lib/Observable.js:197:34)
            at ObservableQuery.subscribe (/home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/node_modules/zen-observable/lib/Observable.js:279:14)
            at QueryData.startQuerySubscription (/home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/node_modules/@apollo/react-hooks/lib/react-hooks.cjs.js:305:52)
            at QueryData._this.getExecuteResult (/home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/node_modules/@apollo/react-hooks/lib/react-hooks.cjs.js:113:13)
            at QueryData.execute (/home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/node_modules/@apollo/react-hooks/lib/react-hooks.cjs.js:160:47)
            at /home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/node_modules/@apollo/react-hooks/lib/react-hooks.cjs.js:518:55
            at useDeepMemo (/home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/node_modules/@apollo/react-hooks/lib/react-hooks.cjs.js:465:14)
            at useBaseQuery (/home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/node_modules/@apollo/react-hooks/lib/react-hooks.cjs.js:517:16)
            at Object.useQuery (/home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/node_modules/@apollo/react-hooks/lib/react-hooks.cjs.js:539:10)
            at Object.useGetProcessInstanceByIdQuery (/home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/packages/management-console/src/graphql/types.tsx:1253:27)
            at ProcessDetailsPage (/home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/packages/management-console/src/components/Templates/ProcessDetailsPage/ProcessDetailsPage.tsx:49:9)
            at renderWithHooks (/home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:15108:18)
            at mountIndeterminateComponent (/home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:17342:13)
            at beginWork$1 (/home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:18486:16)
            at beginWork$$1 (/home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:23193:14)
            at performUnitOfWork (/home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22211:12)
            at workLoopSync (/home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22185:22)
            at renderRoot (/home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21878:11)
            at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (/home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21419:22)
            at scheduleRootUpdate (/home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24319:3)
            at updateContainerAtExpirationTime (/home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24347:10)
            at updateContainer (/home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24436:10)
            at /home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24963:7
            at unbatchedUpdates (/home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21687:12)
            at legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer (/home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24962:5)
            at Object.render (/home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:25042:12)
            at fn (/home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/node_modules/enzyme-adapter-react-16/src/ReactSixteenAdapter.js:437:26)
            at /home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/node_modules/enzyme-adapter-react-16/src/ReactSixteenAdapter.js:354:37
            at batchedUpdates$1 (/home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21643:12)
            at act (/home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-test-utils.development.js:1002:14)
            at Object.act (/home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-test-utils.development.js:1418:12)
            at wrapAct (/home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/node_modules/enzyme-adapter-react-16/src/ReactSixteenAdapter.js:354:13)
            at Object.render (/home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/node_modules/enzyme-adapter-react-16/src/ReactSixteenAdapter.js:423:16)
            at new ReactWrapper (/home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/node_modules/enzyme/src/ReactWrapper.js:115:16)
            at Object.mount (/home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/node_modules/enzyme/src/mount.js:10:10)
            at /home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/packages/management-console/src/components/Templates/ProcessDetailsPage/tests/ProcessDetailsPage.test.tsx:160:21
            at step (/home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/packages/management-console/src/components/Templates/ProcessDetailsPage/tests/ProcessDetailsPage.test.tsx:44:23)
            at Object.next (/home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/packages/management-console/src/components/Templates/ProcessDetailsPage/tests/ProcessDetailsPage.test.tsx:25:53)
            at /home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/packages/management-console/src/components/Templates/ProcessDetailsPage/tests/ProcessDetailsPage.test.tsx:19:71
            at new Promise (<anonymous>)
            at Object.<anonymous>.__awaiter (/home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/packages/management-console/src/components/Templates/ProcessDetailsPage/tests/ProcessDetailsPage.test.tsx:15:12)
            at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/packages/management-console/src/components/Templates/ProcessDetailsPage/tests/ProcessDetailsPage.test.tsx:159:26)
            at Object.asyncJestTest (/home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/jasmineAsyncInstall.js:100:37)
            at /home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:45:12
            at new Promise (<anonymous>)
            at mapper (/home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:28:19)
            at /home/ajaganat/Desktop/Kogito/kogito-apps/kogito-apps/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:75:41,
        message: 'Network error: No more mocked responses for the query: query getProcessInstanceById($id: String) {\n' +
          '  ProcessInstances(where: {id: {equal: $id}}) {\n' +
          '    id\n' +
          '    processId\n' +
          '    processName\n' +
          '    businessKey\n' +
          '    parentProcessInstanceId\n' +
          '    parentProcessInstance {\n' +
          '      id\n' +
          '      processName\n' +
          '      businessKey\n' +
          '    }\n' +
          '    roles\n' +
          '    variables\n' +
          '    state\n' +
          '    start\n' +
          '    lastUpdate\n' +
          '    end\n' +
          '    addons\n' +
          '    endpoint\n' +
          '    addons\n' +
          '    serviceUrl\n' +
          '    error {\n' +
          '      nodeDefinitionId\n' +
          '      message\n' +
          '    }\n' +
          '    childProcessInstances {\n' +
          '      id\n' +
          '      processName\n' +
          '      businessKey\n' +
          '    }\n' +
          '    nodes {\n' +
          '      id\n' +
          '      nodeId\n' +
          '      name\n' +
          '      enter\n' +
          '      exit\n' +
          '      type\n' +
          '      definitionId\n' +
          '    }\n' +
          '  }\n' +
          '}\n' +
          ', variables: {}',
        extraInfo: undefined
      }

      at ProcessDetailsPage (src/components/Templates/ProcessDetailsPage/ProcessDetailsPage.tsx:52:11)
```

can anyone help me find where I am going wrong here? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The variables of the mocked response need to match the request EXACTLY with value and structure. It seems to me you are missing the "equal" prop.
Try configuring your mock like so:

```js
const mocks = [
      {
        request: {
          query: GetProcessInstanceByIdDocument,
          variables: {
            id: { equal: '201a8a42-043e-375a-9f52-57c804b24db4' },
          },
        },
        result: {
          data: {
            someStuff: 'whatever',
          },
        },
      },
    ]
```

Comment: Thanks, I was missing the part `variables: { ... }`